# firefox no internet

Tags: networking, firefox, ssl

In our company we have a proxy that verifies all ssl certificates and terminates the ssl connection itself (i.e. decrypts in the middle), then reencrypts and passes the website to the browser with its own certificate.
The reason is the policy that no end-to-end encryption through the proxy must be allowed without the company cheching what is going on.

How can I set firefox to allow this behaviour (not that I'm found of it, but I have no choice, if I want to use internet at my office, for work only related browsing) ?
I tried to go to settings->advanced->network->settings->automatic proxy configuration url and give the url of the .pac given by my colleague.
But this didn't work, I still have no internet connection and get an error from firefox regarding a SSL certificate issue. This error is not the one where you can say 'accept certificate exception' and add it to the rule, as in "I understand the risks". There is no button or interface, just this error message.

Please give a torough explanation, as I won't be able to access internet to ask details tomorrow.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this something which you should ask the IT department at work to do for you. They can probably add the certificate of the proxy to your firefox setup.

Comment: Yes I guess, but it doesn't work to ask here, does it ? Besides I'm not exactly sure I'm supposed to use firefox, so I'm a bit afraid to ask (and not to mention that it might take a while before I get an answer, and I'd like to use it right now)

Comment: Your company's IT policy is pretty darn intrusive! Apparently they want to see everything you do. A company that wants that level of control is not going to be happy about you tweaking your browser setup yourself. I strongly advise you to talk to IT, not just to solve the problem, but to avoid getting fired.